# Replace variable in JSON file in bash

Tags: json, bash

EDIT: I've updated the question as the answers so far are correct but unfortunately I oversimplified the problem to the point that it will likely need a new question entirely. The issue I'm running into is that I need to replace only a part of value, and that having more than one variable causes `sed` to gobble multiple variables at once.

here's what I've been trying to do:

```json
# test.json
{
  "name": "Mr. ${FIRSTNAME} ${LASTNAME}"
}
```

I'd like to load this file, replace the variable, and store it in a variable:

```bash
NAME=Frodo JSON=$(eval "echo \"$(cat test.json)\"")
echo $JSON
```

I'd like it to print `{ "name": "Mr. Frodo Baggins" }`, however it seems like `eval` is stripping out the double quotes, producing invalid JSON: `{ name: Frodo }`. Any idea on how I can do this?

I should also mention that this approach seemed the cleanest, as the variables act as a key-value map. The other approach I tried was with an associative array and `sed` loop, which seems to work:

```bash
KEYS=( "FIRSTNAME" "LASTNAME" )
VALUES=( "Frodo" "Baggins" )
JSON=$(cat test.json)

for index in "${!KEYS[@]}"; do
  JSON=$(echo "$JSON" | sed -E "s/\\$\{${KEYS[0]}}/${VALUES[0]}/g")
done

echo $JSON
```

NOTE: I'm aware that eval is a security risk, however this script is for testing purposes only

Comment: You should use `jq` to read / create json instead of `eval`

Comment: does jq do variable expansion?

Comment: yup. `jq --arg name "$NAME" -n '{$name}'` would recreate your example

Comment: @errorline1, you could also tell jq to refer to `env.Name`, as in: `Name=Frodo jq -n '{"name": env.Name}'`

Comment: ...and yes, one can write a jq expression to search through an object for strings that match `${anything}` where `anything` is an environment variable. I think I've already done that in answer to a different question elsewhere on this site.

Comment: BTW, using all-caps names for your own variables is bad form: All-caps names are used for variables meaningful to the operating system and the shell; whereas names with at least one lower-case character are reserved for application use. See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, keeping in mind that environment variables and shell variables share a single namespace (as setting a shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the tips, will use your suggestion from now on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## edit for altered OP

I'd write the *script* dynamically, rather than eval during runtime.

```
$: keys=( "FIRSTNAME" "LASTNAME" )
$: values=( "Frodo" "Baggins" )
$: sed "$(for i in "${!keys[@]}"; do echo "s/\${${keys[i]}}/${values[i]}/;"; done)" test.json
{
  "name": "Mr. Frodo Baggins"
}
```

## end edit

First, use `jq` if you can.
That being said...

If you are VERY CAREFUL with your quoting and ORDER of operations, `eval` isn't needed.

```
$: JSON="$(NAME=Frodo; sed s/\${NAME}/$NAME/ json)" && echo "--> $JSON <--"
--> {
  "name": "Frodo"
} <--
```

(When testing, remember to `unset JSON` between runs.) ;)

This does NOT work without the internal semicolon!

```
$: JSON="$(NAME=Frodo sed s/\${NAME}/$NAME/ json)" && echo "--> $JSON <--"
--> {
  "name": ""
} <--
```

Remember, assigning `NAME=Frodo` happens on the same parse of the command line, so you can't use `$NAME` in that pass. It has to either be a subsequent command or a subshell.

This works, because the parse runs in the subshell where the variable *has been* set, rather than *is being* set.

```
$: echo 'sed s/\${NAME}/$NAME/ json' >script
$: JSON="$(NAME=Frodo ./script)" && echo "--> $JSON <--"
--> {
  "name": "Frodo"
} <--
```

Comment: Rarely matters (you'd have to have `IFS` set to include a character that could happen in a valid variable name), but better to use `for i in "${!keys[@]}"` with the quotes; I could see `IFS=_` sometimes being appropriate, f/e.

Comment: Agreed - edited.